# Will AirDrop work between an OS X virtual machine and an iPhone?

Tags: macos, virtualization, airdrop

I'm looking for an easy way to transfer files to my iPhone and I don't have a Mac.

I was going to use VirtualBox or VMware Workstation Player.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here (without already making assumptions about the solution)?

Answer (score 4):

Is your question here really "How do I get files from a Windows computer onto an iPhone", and you're using an OSX VM to enable AirDrop to achieve that?

If so, you can look at several other ways of sharing files:

- DropBox
- iCloud for Windows

And most of the big file-sharing services have iPhone apps that will allow you to upload from the desktop side (OSX, Windows, Linux, etc), and access them on the phone.

Comment: But will AirDrop work from a VM?

Comment: Air Drop is hard enough to get working on an unsupported Mac, let alone one running in a VM on completely unsupported [& incidentally unlicensed] hardware.